# Refer to included libraries in Qt C++ Project

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries

There is a high chance that this might get downvoted, but I am still posting this since I did not find the answer anywhere. I have added a Static External Library to my Project and this is how the MyApp.pro looks like at the moment:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../common/build-CommonLib-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Release/release/ -lCommonLib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../common/build-CommonLib-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Release/release/ -lCommonLibd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../common/build-CommonLib-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Release/release/ -lCommonLib
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../common/build-CommonLib-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Release/release
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../common/build-CommonLib-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Release/release

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../common/build-CommonLib-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Release/release/libCommonLib.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../common/build-CommonLib-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Release/release/libCommonLibd.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../common/build-CommonLib-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Release/release/CommonLib.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../common/build-CommonLib-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Release/release/CommonLibd.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../common/build-CommonLib-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Release/release/libCommonLib.a
```

However, I am still unsure as ***how to refer to the Library (and a specific header file in there) from a header file in my project***. I tried doing `#include<CommonLib/Test.h>` but it does not recognize either `CommonLib` or `CommonLib/Test.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INCLUDEPATH` points to the build directory, while library headers are most likely in the directory with `CommonLib` sources.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed! This was auto-generated code so I did not notice earlier...